# Customise factory-girl linting for presenters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, lint

If I let factory-girl do its standard linting for a presenter, it'll fail, complaining that `save!` isn't implemented.

Is it possible to customise the linting of a presenter such that it only checks that it can successfully build a presenter, but not save it?

Presenter

```
class PostPresenter
  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end
end
```

Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post_presenter do
    post
    initialize_with { new(post) }
  end
end
```

Backtrace

```
/Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:14:in `lint!': The following factories are invalid: (FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError)

* post_presenter - undefined method `save!' for #<PostPresenter:0x007f8c0b67beb8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:4:in `lint!'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:59:in `lint'
    from /Users/agrimm/rails/redacted/spec/support/factory_girl.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:378:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:378:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:357:in `run'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1660:in `block in run_hooks_with'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1660:in `each'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1660:in `run_hooks_with'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1626:in `with_suite_hooks'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:114:in `block in run_specs'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `run_specs'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in `run'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you use `after(:create) { |instance| PresenterClass.new(instance) }`?

Comment: Perhaps add your factory definition to the question as well?

Comment: @max Thanks. I've now added the factory definition for the presenter.

Comment: I removed my answer since you can't actually replace the instance in a callback

Comment: It tried creating a factory for a PORC and it lints just fine when I added `skip_create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `skip_create` to the factory to skip the `to_create` block altogether (which normally calls `#save!`).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post_presenter do
    skip_create
    post
    initialize_with { new(post) }
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could implement a custom `to_save` callback:

```
to_save { post.save! }
```